# How can I schedule only Windows Defender to update itself the moment updates come out?

Tags: windows, windows-update, scheduled-tasks

I schedule Windows updates according to my convenience. I would, however, like Windows Defender to automatically update itself the moment updates are released or at least be able to schedule Windows Defender to update as frequently as possible, without impacting the schedule of all other Windows updates. Can this be done?

UPDATE:
I confirmed this when I saw that the last update check was yesterday and I clicked "check now for updates" and it found and immediately started to install updates for the Defender.

Comment: Isn't this the default behavior of Windows ≥10? The antivirus definitions updates are entirely separate from other Windows Updates - from what are you determining this isn't the case?

Comment: @JW0914 They are separate updates, but they are still distributed through Windows Update.

Comment: @LPChip Right, but the antivirus definitions are auto-updated without user interaction approx. as soon as they're published by default _(provided system is online - see Settings → Update & Security → Windows Security → Virus & threat protection → Virus & threat protection updates → Check for updates → Security Intelligence: "We try to automatically download the most recent intelligence to protect your device against the newest threats")_; if the system is offline, the definitions will be auto-updated, without user interaction, upon connection to the internet.

Comment: @JW0914 There is a delay between the update getting pushed out and it being delivered through Windows Update, and that is what OP wants to speed up even though they don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advise is against it.

I reason this answer because I think this is a classic X-Y problem. You want your Virusscanner to be up to date as best as possible to have the best protection, but you don't know how Windows Defender works and thus don't realise that the default settings already accomplish this.

When Windows Defender scans a file for a signature, and your computer is online, if the signature is not in the local database, it will use an online database to get information which is basically the same as first having the latest definitions and then go offline.

The sole reason to download updates is to also work if the internet connectivity is down at the moment of having a threat.

It is true that every once in a while, the core of Windows Defender is updated too, yes, these really do need to happen through Windows Update, but its missing the point to make your computer update every nanosecond just because maybe that update happens once every 3 or 4 months. Besides, that would mean a full windows update anyway, not just updating the definitions.

A video that does a really good demonstration of this can be watched here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbYx8V2RTjc

Note: this video first shows online with a database that is not up-to-date, and then goes offline and repeats it. So watch till the end.

Comment: Unclear: "When Windows Defender finds a threat, and your computer is online, if the threat is not in the local database". How was the threat found if it wasn't in the local database to start with? (Not all files are uploaded online.) Also, I don't know where you got the figure of "3 or 4 months". I don't downvote that easily, but it seems that you're not up to date on Defender.

Comment: I've edited my post, hope its more clear. The 3 or 4 months is a frame of reference. I read somewhere that the Windows Defender engine itself is not updated as often as the virus definitions. It doesn't need to be. But if a security hole is found or the featureset is updated, then they update the engine as well, something that is pushed through Windows Updates itself, not as a virus definition update. This can happen twice in a month, or not for another 6 months. The latter being more likely.

Comment: Defender is changing all the time and we don't know what is changed with each update, core or signatures. Whatever you have read is either speculation or outdated. My answer is the only way to update only the signatures without going through Windows Update, as Microsoft no longer allows to selectively install updates, so it's all updates or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a scheduled task to (for example) daily update the
Windows Defender antivirus signatures, using the Task Scheduler:

- Run *START > Task Scheduler*
- Right-click on Task Scheduler Library and select "Create Basic Task"
- Type any name for the task and click the Next button
- Set the trigger setting as Daily, and click the Next button
- Leave the daily setting to Recur every 1 days, and click Next
- Leave the action as "Start a program", and click Next
- In the Program/script field enter:
  `"C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe"` (the quotes are required)
- In "Add arguments enter: `-signatureupdate`, and click Next
- Click Finish to complete the task
- Double-click the task and in the General tab, select
  "Run whether user is logged in or not"
- Click OK and enter the password for your account.

Comment: I'm going to vote this answer down. Sorry. Although this is technically correct and does answer the question, This is answering the XY problem rather than going to its core. The core is that the way Windows Defender works as it is, is sufficient because as long the computer is online, The virusscanner will contact with the server to get its latest definitions the moment it encounters an unknown threat anyway.

Comment: @LPChip: Not really. Windows Defender is since several years no longer stand-alone, but its updates are rather now integrated into Windows Update. If Windows Update is blocked from the daily check for updates, or from installing updates, then Windows Defender signatures are not updated. Luckily that the manual update method in my answer still works when one needs to uncouple the two.

Comment: That's not the point I'm making. The point is that Microsoft Defender will work despite its local database being up-to-date if the machine is connected online, something you need for Windows Update anyway.

Comment: I don't understand this comment.

Comment: When a file is scanned, and heuristics don't find a match using the local database, or certain behavior is seen as suspicious, microsoft sends the file to its online servers which always have the latest virus definition. My point is that although it is definitely a good idea to update your local virus definitions every so often, because the online version being used too if available, the reason to manually increase its update frequency is completely unnecessary. Your answer does facilitate how to do it, which is great, but you don't need to in the first place.

Comment: You're trying to impose your ideas on the poster, and I don't agree with the idea that it's completely unnecessary *to the poster*. Your vision of how Defender works sounds incomplete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133008/discussion-between-lpchip-and-harrymc).

Comment: I think we've fully covered the subject and I said what I think should have been said. If you now see fit to undo your downvote, I won't complain.

Comment: I'll remove downvote it, just because I'm in a good mood. That said, if you can find sufficient evidence that clearly states that I'm wrong, I'll happily upvote your answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for extending your good mood to others. These things are contagious.

Comment: My Updates already trigger once daily. I updated my question to clarify. However, LPchip's answer is the best. Although it wouldn't help if you go offline and didn't get a Defender signatures update that was available 6 hours ago but didn't get pushed locally, I'm never offline so I'll accept it.